# How do executive promotions actually happen?

Tags: professionalism

I understand lower management, it's just a job you apply for. But how do people go from that to director or vp? Is it just waiting for your boss to leave and hoping his boss' boss prefers you? Or something else? Like does anyone here have a specific example of someone going from  manager to director or director to vp in an engineer org and they can explain the reasons it happened?

Comment: Hi and welcome! Right now your question is very hypothetical and not a good fit for this website. Are you asking about some particular situation you want help with?

Comment: those are more political or network positions some times, rather than something anyone qualified could apply for and get  Quite often a position is already filled before it's even known to be available.

Comment: Can you give a specific example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Executive promotions happen pretty much like any promotion. A boss / supervisor / higher level manager evaluates the candidate, and if:

- there is a position available and
- the candidate meets the requirements for the position,

then the candidate gets the promotion. The criteria for evaluating the candidate are different, of course, but the process is similar.

Comment: But most times, arnet there a huge number of people qualified?

Comment: Maybe yes, maybe no. But then, that can happen for any job in the company. They advertise a job, and they get hundreds of CV's. As a process, it is the same thing. The details are most likely different.

Comment: Can you give a specific example?

Comment: Not from my own experience. You should be able to find reports on the net about how such things happen. Also, you might find information in biographical books. Usually, what happens at executive level remains at executive level.